# Remove last drawing context from UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, cgcontext

I have this code for drawing on a `UIImageView`, I want to save the drawings into an array and to add a button that removes the last drawing.

How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    lastPoint.y -= 10;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.y -= 10;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        drawImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you think drawing image every time when the touches are received is a good idea. I think creating a drawing once and then saving it to the disk and using the same image later when the touches are received is probably better and more efficient way to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       Declare on NSMutableArray object in .h file
         // in .h file
           NSMutableArray *storage;

        // in .m file and initialize in view did load
           storage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
                if ([self.storage count] < MAX_LINE) {
                if(!mouseSwiped) {
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
                    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
                    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10.0);
                    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
                    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
                    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
                    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
                    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
                    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                    drawImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                }
                NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString      stringWithFormat:@"%d_drawslide__.png", [self.storage count]]];
                        [self.storage addObject:path];
                        NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:drawImage.image, path, nil];
                    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(backuppmage:) toTarget:self withObject:params];
                        [params release];
            }

 }

-(void) backuppmage:(NSMutableDictionary *) params
  {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        for (NSString *key in params) {
              UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[params objectForKey:key];
              [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:key atomically:YES];
              }
         [pool drain];


  }

        // add this method to button click
-(IBAction) undoEraseDrawing:(id) sender {

            if (!isErased && [self.storage count] > 0) {

                [self.storage removeObject:[self.storage lastObject]];

            }

            if ([self.storage count] > 0 && [self.storage lastObject] != nil) {
                drawImage.image = [self getImageWithURL:(NSString *)[self.storage lastObject]];
            } else {
                drawImage.image = nil;
            }
            isErased = NO;

    }


-(UIImage *) getImageWithURL:(NSString *)url
    {
            return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:url];
    }
```